# Limit multiclassification SVM - ANN

Tags: svm, neural-networks, multi-class, bounds, artificial-intelligence

I have some questions on the limits of SVM and ANN for multiclass problem.
I know about "one vs all" and "all vs all" strategies but I only want to know the limit of a unique SVM and ANN.

Is there a theoretical limit on the number of classes that an SVM can learn ?
I suppose that if too many vectors are present, they could overlap and the SVM would stop working correctly.

What about artificial neural networks ? Is it related to the number of output neurons ?

Can we calculate the memory footprint based on the number of vectors and neurons ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question. The limit of a *unique SVM* is two classes. One-vs-one, one-vs-all, ... are all kludges to go from two classes to several by using *several* SVM models.

The memory footprint of an SVM model is proportional to the amount of support vectors, unless the model is linear. If the model is linear, it can always be summarized into a single vector plus bias term.

Comment: What about this alternative proposed ? http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/multiclass-svms-1.html I am not sure to understand the feature vector they are talking about, is it possible to do more than 2 classes with it ?